# how to solve %1 is not a valid win32 application. unable to start piped log program error?

Tags: apache

Trying to use Apache rotateLogs on windows for rotating the Access logs but Apache is not starting and keep throwing error  "%1 is not a valid win32 application. unable to start piped log program error"

```
LogFormat "%h %1 %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" common   
CustomLog "|D:/apache/rotatelogs.exe D:/apache/access.log 5M" commom
```

Apache version: 2.4.33

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The path was not correct. Problem solved after giving the correct path.
Note: For running on windows should add .exe, Otherwise it won't run

CustomLog "|bin/rotatelogs.exe D:/apache/access.log 5M" commom